# how to use $_POST in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey i am trying to retrive data from a basic form .. but when i am using $_POST['field name'] then it gives me nothing .

here is my basic code

form page is:

```
<?php
/**

Template Name: galaxy
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<form action="<?php echo site_url();?>?page_id=8" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name"  /> <input type="submit" value="Send"  />

</form>

</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

when i click submit it redirects to next page but display nothing with this code

```
<?php
/**

Template Name: get_value_galaxy
 */


$name=$_POST['name'];
echo $name;

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: Does $_POST return anything at all? What is displayed if you print_r($_POST) ?

Comment: It display nothing :      Array ( )

Comment: You mentionned that when you submit your form, there's a redirect somewhere. Is the code causing a true redirect? Your $_POST data wouldn't be pushed on the redirect, if there is truly one.

Comment: check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. your post may be getting redirected/rewritten, causing it to show up as a GET on your script.

Comment: @Brett what about the GET can you read it ? `echo $_GET['page_id'];`

Comment: Ya i used $_GET['the_name'] .. but still display none

Comment: I believe 'name' is a reserved word.  Try <input type="text" name="searchvalue" /> and $_POST['searchvalue']

Comment: print_r($_GET)  returns Array ( [page_id] => 8 )

Comment: @Brett $_GET['name'] or try printing out the whole $_GET variable, since key matching typos are a pain to find in debugging.

Comment: <input type="text" name="the_name"  id="the_name" /> I change the name but no effect

Comment: `$_POST['name']` along with `name="the_name"` does not work/match, **IF** that's what you're doing. You can also try `action=""`

Comment: Yes sure i also change the the field value when retrivng data.. but alas still no effect

Comment: <form action="<?php echo site_url();?>?page_id=8">  i change this then it redirects me to not found page and my url changes to http://localhost/galaxy/?the_name=testval

Comment: It sounds like either something is rewriting your $_POST variable (could be a module or other script), or you're getting some form of redirect working.  If you press F5 it should prompt you to resend the data, if not then there is a redirect in place.

Comment: Hi @Brett, if any of below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the best answer or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different name for the variable. I know that Wordpress uses "name" as a public query var, and perhaps that's why it's not working. So rather than using `name="name"`, try this:

Form:

```
<input type="text" name="unique_name" />
```

Post Page:

```
$name=$_POST['unique_name'];
echo $name;
```

See this list for all query vars:
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables

Comment: <input type="text" name="unique_name"  id="unique_name" /> 
and also tried $name=$_REQUEST['unique_name'];
echo $name; but nothing happen

Comment: Well $_POST works pretty much the same in wordpress as it would in a normal PHP file. If it's not the variable, it is likely the form action. Make sure your URL is correct, and that there are no syntax errors in it.

Comment: Also, just a note, when you do get it working, I'd recommend utilizing the sanitize_key() function which is built into WordPress to sanitize the data input by the user. Like so: $name=sanitize_key($_POST['unique_name']);

Answer (score 0):

It seems WordPress don't have a method to get $_POST, so you may be able to access it directly.

However, it is recommended to sanitize its data. Here are some ways of doing it:

```php
$valueFromPOST = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$valueFromGET = htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']);

$anyString = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']); //wordpress way
```

Also, consider adding a [nonce validation](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/nonces/) to avoid XSS and some robots...